What is required for a Solana token to always show up in wallets?
I have created an SPL token and it seems to show in some wallets, some it says 'unknown' and others doesn't show at all.
What is required for the token to always show as a verified token in wallets?
Here's my token's contract address: GK28U5k7CNu6kyewYBeyzoogetWjiYakEhas5LNBDwmC
I have added metadata with name, ticker, image and external links etc.
Is the token perhaps not showing because it's not listed on a DEX yet?

Some wallets may not be using the new token-22 metadata to fetch the metadata for the token. Some still use the metaplex metadata program: https://developers.metaplex.com/token-metadata

Check if the wallet supports SPL tokens as not all wallets do and some may require manual configuration.
Two things to do that might solve this issue would be to:

update your metadata
Contact wallet providers.

